# How to get left-aligned cocos2d menu

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

So I want my main menu to have a ccMenu. I tried exploring with align vertically and alignItemsInColumns but all these options center the items within the menu. If I wanted something that looked like this:

**Title**

```
 Option 1 has a very long name
 Option 2 is short
 Shorter
```

instead of this:

**Title**

```
Option 1 has a very long name
     Option 2 is short
          Shorter
```

How could I achieve this in cocos2d? Thanks for the help.

**EDIT:**

I tried using this code but I got this result:

```
CCLabelTTF * sin = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Single Player" dimensions:CGSizeMake(120,    25) alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft fontName:font fontSize:20];
CCMenuItem * item1 = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:sin target:self selector:@selector(goToSinglePlayer:)];

CCLabelTTF * spl = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Splitscreen" dimensions:CGSizeMake(100, 25) alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft fontName:font fontSize:20];
CCMenuItem * item2 = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:spl target:self selector:@selector(goToSplitscreen:)];

CCLabelTTF * ach = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Achievements" dimensions:CGSizeMake(130, 25) alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft fontName:font fontSize:20];
CCMenuItem * item3 = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:ach target:self selector:@selector(goToAchievements:)];

CCLabelTTF * str = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Store" dimensions:CGSizeMake(50, 25) alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft fontName:font fontSize:20];
CCMenuItem * item4 = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:str target:self selector:@selector(goToStore:)];

CCLabelTTF * set = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Settings" dimensions:CGSizeMake(80, 25) alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft fontName:font fontSize:20];
CCMenuItem * item5 = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:set target:self selector:@selector(goToSettings:)];

CCMenu * mainMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, nil];

[mainMenu setColor:ccBLACK];
[mainMenu alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:10];
mainMenu.position =  ccp(size.width/6, size.height/2);
[self addChild:mainMenu];
```

[image: Game Screen]

Seems like it didn't do anything. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: you gave each label a different size .... if you give them all the maximum width you will have ... they will align agains themselves inside the menu. And since you left aligned the text inside the labels, it will all come out below (see my notes below).

Comment: Oh ok great! But if I make all of them the same size, then I could activate a shorter label like Store by tapping on the space next to store

Comment: true ... i view that as a feature personally :), that is why i go that route. You could set the position of the CCMenuItem's individually, by offsetting them in x by -(maxLabelWidth - thisLabelWidth)/2, this would give you touch handling exactly as you would want it, as well as left alignment.

Comment: Yea I thought about that, but this is good for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a menu with CCMenuItemLabel items. Create each label with CCLabelTTF, giving it left alignment and known dimensions. When you add the menuItems to the menu, they will align if all have the same dimensions.

added :

```
 CGSize label = CGSizeMake(160., 45.); 
 CCLabelTTF *label1 = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Option1 for example" 
                                       dimensions:size 
                                        alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft
                                         fontName:@"pickYourOwnFont" fontSize:16.];

 CCLabelTTF *label2 = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Option2 below option 1" 
                                       dimensions:size 
                                        alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft 
                                         fontName:@"pickYourOwnFont" fontSize:16.];
CCMenuItem * item1 = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:label1];
CCMenuItem * item2 = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:label2];
CCMenu * leftAlignedMenu=[CCMenu menuWithItems:item1,item2,nil];
```

you can set whatever properties you like to the labels (color, etc...) and the menuItem's (callback target and selector).

Comment: I think this is what you mean but my app crashes if I add this to a menu.IT says "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Menu only supports MenuItem objects as children'":    CCMenuItem * item = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Item 1" dimensions:CGSizeMake(50, 20) alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft fontName:@"Verdana" fontSize:20];

Comment: and how could i use that with a selector?

Comment: Thanks for the code, it passed but it seems like it had no effect.

Answer (score 4):

A more generic solution (that doesn't require the use of a CCLabel) would be to just adjust the anchor point, and then align vertically i.e.

```
CCMenuItem * testItem = ...
testItem.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0.5f);
[testItem alignItemsVertically]
```

Comment: this is a better answer

Answer (score 2):

```
CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Hello World"
                                     dimensions:CGSizeMake(480, 100)
                                      alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft
                                       fontName:@"Marker Felt"
                                       fontSize:64];

CCMenuItemLabel *labelItem = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:label
                                                     target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(labelPressed)];
```

Use it like this... Hope this helps.. :)